# DJango INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

I am just curious, Is it okay to remove some of the default Installed Apps in DJango Settings? See image below.

[image]

These apps creates a new tables in my database and I don't know when can I use those tables.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: No, you should not remove those. One usecase would be for example, you get the admin interface - How would you login to that if you get rid of the auth tables? Also, I would encourage you to read about django content types which is a very integral part of the framework.

Comment: @karthikr Thank you for replying and for your suggestiong, really appreciated it. Okay, I'll just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can, though if you're unsure the purpose of the app it would be best to leave it included.

In fact, the Django documentation mentions this in the very first tutorial:

> Like we said above, the default applications are included for the common case, but not everybody needs them. If you don’t need any or all of them, feel free to comment-out or delete the appropriate line(s) from INSTALLED_APPS before running migrate. The migrate command will only run migrations for apps in INSTALLED_APPS.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/